# Convert Date/Time Format using PHP

Tags: php

Ok I can't work out the correct way to convert this using PHP.

This is the current output format of the Date/Time string looks like this

```
2014-03-12 14:38:00
```

I am trying to get it to look like this...

```
2014-03-12T14:38:38+00:00
```

What is the correct time conversion for this type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) objects:

```
$dateObj = new DateTime('2014-03-12 14:38:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $dateObj->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

Comment: Fantastic - Just what i was looking for :) Works perfect.

Comment: Have done bro, was just waiting for the time limit to complete.

Comment: @MattTheNinja: Sure. Glad to have helped. Removed the other comment as it's not going to be useful for a future visitor. :) Cheers!